# Registration blanket, database, info, wordpress, mySQL, e-mail

Tags: php, database, wordpress, email

I'm making websites for a company where users have to "register" with names and a lot of different information to attend the event. (It's a video-event - info would be name, e-mail etc.)

I now got a Wordpress webpage, at the blanket doesn't necessary need to be on the site, but can open in a separate window.

I need to, somehow make it easy for admin to look at the users who registered, send them e-mails etc. Make a list of everyone who register, for the admin to see.

How would be the easiest way to do this?
I know how to make a form, and pull the information into the database..

Any good ideas, plugins or examples??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla comes in with mass emails, although I have not tried it.

Have You searched on Wordpress plugins? They may have what you are looking for.

Comment: Yep. I've tried.
But the problem is that it kinda have to be seperate. Yes you have to send e-mails to the people who registered, but people who haven't registered also have to be able to get an e-mail with info.
i will try and look further.

Comment: Then you would have to make the email madatory for that? cause even unregistered users you still want to email them.